# Re: Complete beginner learning issue with Matrix multiplication

Tags: r

I'm learning R in hopes to career change and I'm a bit stumped with Matrix multiplication.

From "The book of R" by Tilman M. Davies there is an exercise (3.2) which request the following:

[image: PDF snippit]

Am I right in thinking that (i. A.B) in question b. is not possible due to there being 1 row for A and 1 for B?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Kamil, this looks like more a math answer. Please, go to https://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Yes the matrix multiplication A.B without transposing A or B is incorrect.

You can learn more over [here](https://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/matrix/multiply-matrix.php)

However, this is a mathematical question and not an R question. I think this is the wrong forum to post your question.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance all!